# CSS: How to place divs on top of each other

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsxo0xmd/12/)

I am trying to place the div `#popup` at the bottom of the page, overlapping any previous content and

- having the width of his parent (`#content`)
- the width of his parent is not given

I am not sure, but I think `position: absolute` does not work in this case, at least not in the way I implemented it.

How would I do that?

Comment: `position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;`

Comment: My answer work in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to using the `position: absolute` for a popup like this is to ensure that the container is set to `position: relative`. Additionally, you will need to set the z-index to ensure that the popup is shown above the content and set the location using the top property.

To meet the requirement of having the pop up be the width of the content, you could just set `width: 100%`

```
#content {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
#popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xsxo0xmd/18/

Technically, you can use `position: absolute` with any container that is not set to `position : static` (the default value for position), as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> The absolutely positioned
>   element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor
>   (non-static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial
>   container is used.

For an illustrative guide to using absolute positioning inside relative positioning, check out https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Append this to your CSS for the said element:

```
#popup {
    position: fixed; //this is your friend
    bottom: 0;  //stick to bottom
    z-index: 1; //bring the element in front of other element.
}
```

I've updated the JSFiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/xsxo0xmd/15/

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute is needed, As you want width to be taken from parent.
Due to postion:absolute the element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. Also you want that container as pop up, which will be achieved through z-index.

FYI Please check updated

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').click(
        function(){
            popup = $('#popup');
            if (popup.hasClass('show')) {
                popup.slideUp(250, function() {
                    popup.fadeOut(250).removeClass('show');
                });
            } else {
                popup.slideDown(250, function() {
                    popup.fadeIn(250).addClass('show');
                });
            };
        }
    );
});
```

```css
    .CodeMirror {
      height: calc(100vh - 25px);
      width: 100%;
    }
    #content {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color:green;
    }
    #popup {
      display: none;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body, {
   value: "function myScript(){return 100;}",
    mode:  "javascript",
    lineSeparator: null,
    theme: "default", // theme directory
    indentUnit: 2,
    smartIndent: true,
    tabSize: 2,
    indentWithTabs: false,
    electricChars: true,
    extraKeys: null,
    lineWrapping: false,
    lineNumbers: true,
    firstLineNumber: 1,
    scrollbarStyle: "overlay",
    inputStyle: "contenteditable",
    readOnly: false, // also "nocursor"
    showCursorWhenSelecting: false,
    lineWiseCopyCut: true,
    undoDepth: 200,
    historyEventDelay: 1250,
    autofocus: true
  });
</script>
  
 <div id="content">
   ABC
   <div id="popup">
     DEF
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `z-index: 2` on `.popup`

And for `#content` use `z-index: 1`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tom613/99pz9jo3/2/)

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: can you check my answer